# If cookie contain only contain 4KB data, how does site like google store so much information

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

Based on ad preferences on chrome setting, I observed that there were much information for google to show relevant ads. However, when I check the document.cookie ( or cookie on the application tab after console ), I only see few information like __ga ( google analytics ).

1. How are this much information store; like my researches, my clicks, my interest?
2. What key=value pairs are used?

For example, I could make 7 researches at a time using different tabs. I'm sure that if a cookie like `search=what is cookie` were to be written again as `search=why do we need cookie`, the second will overwrite the first, yet, those information does not seem to be overwritten and are still not made accountable in the cookie document.

If they are stored else where, what format are they being stored in and how are they able to group a list of information in just one cookie key?

Answer (score 0):

One way this could be done is for the cookie to only hold *one* critical piece of information: a unique identifier for your device and/or account. Then, when one of Google's services needs to check, say, your interests, or relevant ads, etc, it will look up your identifier in *Google's server-side database* to retrieve the information.

It's not stored on your browser; it's stored on Google's servers. Databases can be massive, unlike cookies.